# Allow only Selects for a MySQL user with many privileges

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am creating a database application that provides dynamic views of any database. For security features, I want to only allow selects.  Can this simply be done by checking if the first word is select?  I know that I should have another created user with limited permissions but I am trying to avoid that so that my app is easy to use.

Basically, can someone give me an example query of where SELECT is the first word but the data can actually be altered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of a SELECT statement that can modify data (it's an obscure corner case, but it demonstrates that it *IS* possible to cause data to be modified with a SELECT)

```
SELECT udf_myfunction()
```

Given, e.g.:

```
CREATE FUNCTION udf_myfunction() RETURNS INT
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM dummy_table1;
   UPDATE dummy_table2 SET mycol = CONCAT(mycol,SUBSTR(mycol,1,1));
   RETURN 0;
END
```

(Of course, the user would need to be granted `EXECUTE` privilege on the function, in order for the function to be executed.)

Comment: Good point, thank you for this.  I guess I will make sure the user can't create functions.

Answer (score 2):

> can someone give me an example query of where SELECT is the first word
>   but the data can actually be altered?

<del>No such thing. `SELECT` is for data reading only.</del>  Unless, of course, your are selecting a function that alters data. See @spencer7593 answer.

However, you might want to check for row blocking `SELECT` commands and also avoid them, since it appears that you will open your DB to 3rd parties.

Further reading:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html